# Polynomial fitting problems in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to implement a standard polynomial fitting program, and came across a problem that I could not understand. Here is the code where I have a sample x and y data, which I fit using the normal equations, and also using the polyfit function in numpy.

```
def mytest(N):
    print "\nPolynomial order (N): {}".format(N)
    mVals = [5, 10, 15, 20]
    a_orig = [198.764, 13.5, 0.523]
    for M in mVals:
        x = arange(-M, M+1)
        y = matrix(a_orig[0]+ a_orig[1]*x + a_orig[2]*x**2).T

        # Code implementing the solution from the normal equations
        nArray = arange(N+1)    
        A = matrix([[n**i for i in nArray] for n in x])
        B = (A.T*A).I
        a_myfit = B*(A.T*y)

        # numpy's polyfit    
        a_polyfit = polyfit(x, y, N)

        print "M: {}".format(M)
        print ["{0:0.3f}".format(i) for i in a_orig] 
        print ["{0:0.3f}".format(i) for i in array(a_myfit)[:,0]]
        print ["{0:0.3f}".format(i) for i in list(array(a_polyfit)[:,0])[::-1]]

mytest(N=5)
mytest(N=6)
```

Here is the output

```
Polynomial order (N): 5
M: 5
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '0.000', '0.000', '-0.000']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '-0.000', '0.000', '0.000']
M: 10
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '-0.000', '0.000', '-0.000']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000']
M: 15
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '0.000', '0.000', '-0.000']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '-0.000', '-0.000', '0.000']
M: 20
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '0.000', '-0.000', '-0.000']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000']

Polynomial order (N): 6
M: 5
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '0.000', '0.000', '-0.000', '-0.000']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '-0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '-0.000']
M: 10
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '-0.000', '-0.000', '-0.000', '-0.000']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '0.000', '0.000', '-0.000', '-0.000']
M: 15
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523']
['294.451', '13.500', '-0.061', '0.000', '-0.001', '-0.000', '-0.000']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '-0.000']
M: 20
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523']
['369.135', '13.500', '-0.046', '0.000', '-0.000', '-0.000', '-0.000']
['198.764', '13.500', '0.523', '0.000', '0.000', '-0.000', '-0.000']
```

The values of the polynomial fit gives wrong values for N > 5 and for M > 13.

Where am I going wrong? What is different in the polyfit implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` is of dtype `int32`.

The maximum value representable is:

```
In [10]: np.iinfo(np.dtype('int32')).max
Out[10]: 2147483647
```

When the exponent is very large, `n**i` can become larger than 2147483647. At this point you get an incorrect result.

[NumPy does not check for arithmetic overflows](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/29300) (when performing operations on arrays) since this would hinder performance. It is up to you to select a dtype which avoids arithmetic overflow.

To fix the problem, declare a different dtype which can represent larger numbers:

```
A = np.matrix([[n**i for i in nArray] for n in x], dtype='float64')
```

Note that the problem still exists, it will just occur at a much larger value of `N`.